# BigQuery SQL Query Question - UPDATE command in bulk

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If I am trying to update more than just one column in my table that I created forApple devices in our IT environment.. What would I need to add to my Query? Currently I have this to update one column only, with the ASSIGNED_TO_USER being one of the columns, and inserting "test_user" into the row below for the column SERIAL_NO. I was wondering how I would update more than just one column with a different value in one query..

Thanks :)

```
UPDATE production-1.Devices.AppleDevices
SET ASSIGNED_TO_USER = "test_user"
WHERE SERIAL_NO = "DMPTQGA9HLF9"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply comma separate the list like:

```
UPDATE production-1.Devices.AppleDevices
SET ASSIGNED_TO_USER = "test_user"
  , col_2=‘abc’
WHERE SERIAL_NO = "DMPTQGA9HLF9"
```

You can find the documentation for Bigquery’s implementation here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement

Comment: Wow, you are a legend! Thank you!